# Pygame: paint a Class polygon from a different module

Tags: python, pygame

**History:**
*Achievement not understand what is wrong with my code, first time you use a class to create a figure.*

*I have a module where is the Polygon class in it have the following code:*

```
import pygame

class Polygon:
    def __init__(self,):
         self.list_puntos = [(200, 30), (250, 80), (225, 130), (175, 130),(150 ,80)]
         self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 36))
         self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
def draw(self):
    self.pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, (255, 0, 255), self.list_puntos)

def cursors(self):
    pass
```

*I have a Kernel with the following code:*

```
 import sys
 import pygame
 from Objects import Polygon



 call_polygon = Polygon






class Kernel:
    def __init__(self):
         pygame.init()

         self.screen_size = (800,  600)
         self.bg_color = (120, 120, 250)
         self.fps = 60
         self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
         self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()



    def handle_input(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    def update(self):
        capition = "Music Art - FPS: {:.2f}".format(self.clock.get_fps())
        pygame.display.set_caption(capition)

    def render(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)



    def main_loop(self):

        while True:
            self.handle_input()
            self.update()
            self.render()
            call_polygon.draw()
  """TypeError: unbound method draw() must be called with Polygon instance   as first argument (got nothing instead)"""



            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)



    if __name__ == '__main__':
             Module_game = Kernel()
             Module_game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes only define a "template" for a certain type of object. To actually create an object (or "instance") of that type, the class must be called and passed any data needed to complete its definition as arguments. Not hardcoding the data into the class itself will allow you to create more than one instance of the class and each one can have different attributes depending on what values are given — such as color, shape, position, etc — when it's created.

With that in mind, I would change your code as follows. It still only has one polygon, but more could easily be added now just by calling `Polygon()` multiple times and storing the instances returned so their `draw()` method can be called when necessary.

File `Objects.py`:

```
import pygame

class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, *puntos):
        self.puntos = puntos

    def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw the shape on the surface. """
        pygame.draw.polygon(surface, (255, 0, 255), self.puntos)

    def cursors(self):
        pass
```

Main game module file:

```
from Objects import Polygon
import pygame
import sys

class Kernel:
    def __init__(self):
         pygame.init()
         self.screen_size = (800,  600)
         self.bg_color = (120, 120, 250)
         self.fps = 60
         self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.screen_size)
         self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
         self.polygon = Polygon((200, 30), (250, 80), (225, 130), (175, 130),
                                (150 ,80))  # define shape here, not in class

    def handle_input(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        capition = "Music Art - FPS: {:.2f}".format(self.clock.get_fps())
        pygame.display.set_caption(capition)

    def render(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            self.handle_input()
            self.update()
            self.render()
            self.polygon.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module_game = Kernel()
    module_game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the `Polygon` class, not just try to call methods on the class directly:

```
poly = Polygon() # call the class to create an instance; put this in your setup code 

poly.draw() # put this in your main loop
```